# Boolean difference adding

Tags: modeling, modifiers

The boolean difference is adding on to the outside of my object.

I have tried the things I can try, if I didn't it was because I could find how to do it or I did not find anything on it.

I have a traced shape from an image and its part of a logo. I am trying to cut that part of the logo out of a block and it is not working.

I have gotten a different object to work with the boolean difference but I still cannot get the part of the logo to work.

[image]

Comment: hello, there must be a problem with your logo topology, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some overlapping vertices in your letter. These break the boolean. Your normals are also inside out and should be flipped.

### Merge by Distance

[image: Merge by distance]

Select your cutter and toggle to Edit Mode <kbd>Tab</kbd>. Press <kbd>A</kbd> to select all. Under Mesh tab select Clean Up and Merge by Distance.

[image: result]

### Recalculate Normals

[image: Face orientation]

From Viewport Overlays panel you can check Face Orientation checkbox. This lets you see which way your normals are facing. Blue should be outside and red should be inside.

[image: Recalculate outside]

To recalculate the normals select your object toggle to Edit Mode. Select all and Under Mesh tab choose Normals and Recalculate Outside. You should do this to both of your objects.

Comment: Thank you so much